# Why is Department not in Instructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was looking at this example from

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

and i came across something i can not understand.

One instructor can be related to many departments, but a department may or may not be related to an instructor.

Class for Instructor:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Instructor
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("FirstName")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",       ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class for Department:

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
   public class Department
   {
      public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

      [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=3)]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
      [Column(TypeName = "money")]
      public decimal Budget { get; set; }

      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
      [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
      public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

      public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

      public virtual Instructor Administrator { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
   }
}
```

My question is: Shouldn't Instructor class have a

```
public int? DepartmentID {get; set;}
Public Virtual Department Department {get; set;}
```

If not, then why?

Comment: If an `Instructor` had a set `DepartmentID`, then they wouldn't be able to be in multiple departments.  You have to check the `Department` to see which `Instructor`s are in that `Department`, but you can't check an `Instructor` to see which `Department`s they belong to.  (at least the way it is currently set up)

Comment: so then public virtual Icollection<Department> Department {get; set:} can work?

Comment: Yes, that could work.  I would recommend naming it `Departments` though, plural, since it is a collection.  That way it makes more sense to access `Instructor.Departments` knowing that there can be more than one.